# Recommended Commodity Price Datasets

Tags: data-request, paneldata, commodities

I am working on a project involving bond issuance and commodities.

I'm wondering whether anyone has any recommendations for the best commodity price data sets for economic research. Ideally, I would like monthly prices.

I have access to Bloomberg, Refinitiv/LSEG, and a slew of other services through my university, but I am looking for a second opinion before bothering my supervisor.

Thanks!

Comment: What commodities? Futures, OTC, spot, ... Realistically, I don't think the source matters much unless it's something very specific.

Comment: @AKdemy, spot and futures. It looks like metals and energy are going to be the most important. I would use the IMF commodities index, but a friend of mine from industry said those data sets are essentially a fiction.

What I should have specified in my question is that I would be interested in aggregations around energy or metals, for example, rather than dealing with specific commodities.

Comment: Not sure how you would aggregate commodities in any meaningful way. Delivery will be different. Location plays a huge role, especially for energy. Probably best to ask your advisor. This isn't really an economics question either. I don't think Bloomberg and LSEG will be very good for energy to be honest, although for something like aggregated data it's probably fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commodity prices are available in Refinitiv (at least Datastream-Refinitiv) and Bloomberg has good data !